# Find a particular value within a table jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to find a give value from the a table. How can I do it using jquery. I don't want to loop through the entire table like this

```
$('table tr td').each(function(){}
```

Is there a better way of doing it. Value meaning `<td>value</td>`. The value between a cell

Comment: What do you mean by "value"? Is it of an `<input />` element? Is it the HTML/text content of a cell?

Comment: In both cases, jQuery would loop anyway.

Comment: and what you don't like about loop? it will loop anyway

Comment: "Value meaning value." ??????

Comment: so what does a selector does if not "looping through"?

Comment: If you guys please read my question properly I said I didn't want to loop through the table like this meaning to say I didn't want to use the each function. Sorry for not being clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [`:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$('table td:contains("some text")')
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's text inside the cell, try this:

```
$("#myTbl tr td:contains(World)").attr("style","color:red");
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/cnSgV/